# FFmpeg package for php

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Does simple ffmpeg package also work fine when we execute its command from PHP via exec? Or we have some different ffmpeg package for that purpose?
Please help me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** simple `ffmpeg` does work through PHP exec if you have necessary permissions.

Sample command

```
<?php

     /*** convert video to flash ***/
     exec("ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv");

?>
```

**[Source](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html)**

Comment: but i want to run it on browser. I know this php script runs on terminal but it is not working on  browser. Does executing it on browser through PHP exec requires simple ffmpeg.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, Not neccessarily mate. Maybe his web's php.ini haven't got the exec enabled.

Comment: will this PHP exec script for ffmpeg command work on browser?? actually i want to run it through browser

Comment: how to enable that in my php.ini file please help

Comment: This works perfectly from browser if you have enough permissions to execute an `exec` command !

Comment: @Alifaizan, Are you on shared hosting server ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP's ffmpeg and the vanilla ffmpeg are independent packages. The `php5-ffmpeg` package comes with the ffmpeg binary as a dynamic library. This means that you can install only `php5-ffmeg` without installing the command line `ffmpeg` package or vice versa or you can have both of them installed.

Therefore, the answer is yes, PHP will work with the command line `ffmpeg` given it is installed.

I usually prefer using the command line ffmpeg in PHP via `exec`. This allows for testing certain operations on the command line and once the result is as desired, the command can be used in PHP's `exec`. On the other hand, in some situations, it may be preferable to use the `php5-ffmpeg` package because it gives you the ability to use object oriented coding style when dealing with videos, conversion, etc.

Comment: my php exec script for ffmpeg is working fine but now i also want to run this php script for ffmpeg in browser. does that also works with simple ffmpeg package??

Comment: If it works in a command line, it should work in PHP `exec` as well. One hint is to use full path to ffmpeg (use the output of `which ffmpeg`). Another hint if it doesn't work in exec is to examine the output and the return value from `exec` by passing the 2nd and 3rd optional parameters to it.